TensorFlow 2.17.0 Error: tf.where() not working as expected after update
After updating TensorFlow to version 2.17.0, I'm encountering an error in a part of my model that previously worked fine. The error occurs when using tf.where() to create a gate based on a probability threshold.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
x_prob = layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=kernel_size_last, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=K_INIT, padding='same', name='x_prob')(x)
x_loc = layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=kernel_size_last,  activation="hard_sigmoid", kernel_initializer=K_INIT, padding='same', name='x_loc')(x)
x_width = layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=kernel_size_last,  activation="linear", kernel_initializer=K_INIT, padding='same', name='x_width')(x)

gate = tf.where(x_prob > 0.5, tf.ones_like(x_prob), tf.zeros_like(x_prob))
x_loc = x_loc * gate
x_width = x_width * gate

x = layers.Concatenate()([x_prob, x_loc, x_width])

The error occurs on the line with tf.where():
File ~/anaconda3/envs/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb
...
        return tf_fn(x)

x = MyLayer()(x)

What could be causing this error after updating to TensorFlow 2.17.0?
How can I modify my code to make it work with the new version?

The error arises because you're trying to use KerasTensor in a TensorFlow function tf.where().
KerasTensors are symbolic tensors used for building keras models and they are not directly compatible with TensorFlow functions which expect eager tensors.
This can be achieved by either creating a custom Keras layer(keras model) or by using a Lambda layer.
Use Lambda layer to wrap tf.where()
gate = layers.Lambda(lambda x_prob: tf.where(x_prob > 0.5, tf.ones_like(x_prob), tf.zeros_like(x_prob)))(x_prob) 

This allows us to perform the operation directly within the model's computational graph, enabling the use of KerasTensors.
You can refer the attached replicated gist for your reference.
